# Email with the iPhone

Tags: iphone, validation, email

Im using this code to allow users to send an email through my application:

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender {
   MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;
   NSArray *emailAddresses;
   emailAddresses=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: email.text,nil];

   mailComposer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
   mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate=self;
   [mailComposer setToRecipients:emailAddresses];
   [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];

   [emailAddresses release];
   [mailComposer release];

}
```

I was wondering, is there any way I can make it so that when users click the button, the To: field is already filled out?

Also, is it possible to validate the CC: field as well (e.g. checking for an @ sign etc.)?

Thanks,
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

The To: field is set using this code:

```
   [mailComposer setToRecipients:emailAddresses];
```

Basic validation is done for you

[image: iOS Simulator]

If you want to do additional validation, then prompt for the To/CC/BCC fields before you show the MFMailComposeViewController, and do the validation as part of the UITextField input.